# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n^3})^n = 1$ using definition of limit

Tags: limits, exponentiation

I cannot seem to understand how to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n^3})^n = 1$ through the usual $|a_n-l|<\epsilon$. I must do this using no other theorem, just the definition.

Doing it for $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n^3}) = 1$ is really easy, but I do not know how to handle the exponentiation.

Thank you very much for any help.

EDIT: An example of proof would go like this:

$\epsilon>0, \forall N>n$

$|1-\frac{1}{n^3}-1|=|-\frac{1}{n^3}|=\frac{1}{n^3}<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$

$N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

Clarification:

$\epsilon>0, \forall N>n$

I need to find what is the value of $N$ in relation to $\epsilon$ when:

$|(1-\frac{1}{n^3})^n-1|<\epsilon$ (the only manipulation allowed being the ones I showcased in my example).

Comment: Probably  $(1+\frac{1}{n^3})^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom n k \frac{1}{n^{3k}}$ could be useful.

Comment: You can't even use sandwich theorem?

Comment: Use the double inequality $$1\leqslant1+\frac1{n^3}\leqslant e^{1/n^3}$$

Comment: @lisyarus I don't know how I could take advantage of that, making use of an infinite sum just with the definition of convergence throws me off.

Comment: @P.Hagemann Nope, only the definition.

Comment: @Did, same problem, I can't use the sandwich theorem.

Comment: $$\left|\left(1+\frac1{n^3}\right)^n-1\right|\leqslant\left|e^{1/n^2}-1\right|=\left|e^{1/n^2}-e^0\right|\leqslant e\cdot\left(\frac1{n^2}-0\right)=\frac{e}{n^2}\to0$$

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga The sum is finite. You can try to show that all summands, except the one for $k=0$, sum up to something negligible,  obtain a strict bound, and use it for a $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof. This is somewhat bruteforce, but should work.

Comment: @lisyarus The number of summands grows with $n$.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, it clearly does. How does it prevent one from obtaining some bound for the whole sum?

Comment: I'll edit my original question to include a simple demonstration in the form that I'm allowed to use. I cannot use a $\epsilon - \delta$ proof, nor the sandwich theorem. How can I show that a $n$-big sum of negligible values ends up to something actually negligible when $n$ approaches infinity?

Comment: "I cannot use a ϵ−δ proof" Funny, your edit is just that, an epsilon-N proof. What is your question, actually?

Comment: How can you not use an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof?  The very definition of a limit depends upon it.  It is not so hard to prove that if $f(x)$ is continuous at $L$  and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = L$ then $\lim_{x\to a} (f \circ g) (x) = f(L)$  in which case $\lim_{x\to a} \ln( g (x)) = \ln L$

Comment: I am sorry I've always seen the $\epsilon - \delta$ proof as related to continuous functions, while in this case I'm dealing with a sequence. It's true however that it is the same as using N. I know that it is not hard to prove the properties of limits, but I'm not allowed to use them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I tried to explain it as best as I could, what should I do more?

Comment: "what should I do more?" Perhaps you could do "less" rather than "more"... That is, as already mentioned, avoid giving as example of a proof you would accept, an epsilon-N proof, after having mentioned that you want to avoid epsilon-N proofs.

Comment: @Did I am sorry for the misunderstanding but I was actually looking for an epsilon-N proof, I just didn't connect that it was the the same as epsilon-delta (I know this sounds really dumb). Anyway now my question is solved so thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) for $n\geq 2$ $$\left(1-\frac1{n^3+1}\right)^n\geq 1-\frac{n}{n^3+1}>1-\frac1{n^2}$$ and taking reciprocals $$\left(1+\frac1{n^3}\right)^n < \frac1{1-\frac1{n^2}} = 1+\frac1{n^2-1}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I find your approach to be the simplest and quickest.

Comment: simplest possible answer +1

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga Bernouilli's inequality ?this is not natural.

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on lisyarus comment:

$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}}\frac{1}{n^{3k}}
$$
and therefore

$$
\left|\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^n-1\right|=\sum_{k=1}^n {{n}\choose{k}}\frac{1}{n^{3k}}=R(n)
$$

Now, you need to find $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $R(n)<\varepsilon$. This can be done using the fact that

$$
{{n}\choose{k}}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\leq \frac{n^k}{k!}.
$$

But then

$$
R(n)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n^k}{k!}\frac{1}{n^{3k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k!n^{2k}}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}.
$$

Therefore, if one takes $N=1/\varepsilon$, we have that $n>N$ implies $R(n)\leq\varepsilon$ (strictly if $\varepsilon<1$).

Comment: I see how it could be done this way too, however I think this solution is a bit complex given the simplicity of the limit in question. Thank you for helping me understand what lisyarus meant!

Comment: Well, if you cannot use the squeeze theorem, you have to be able to bound $R(n)$ somehow. In my opinion, this approach, although long and boring, only uses standard formulas and *obvious* inequalities.

Comment: Yes I agree, I like your solution and I find it very well-explained and coherent. Just one remark, in the binomial coefficient I guess you meant to put $n$, not $N$?

Comment: Yes. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n^3})^n$$

Given an $\epsilon>0$,

We have

$$ln(a_n)=n ln(1+\frac{1}{n^3})$$

$$=n(\frac{1}{n^3}(1+\epsilon(n))),$$

with $\lim_{n\to\infty}\epsilon(n)=0$.

this gives

$$ln(a_n)=\frac{1}{n^2}(1+\epsilon(n))$$

and

$$a_n=e^{\frac{1}{n^2}(1+\epsilon(n)) }$$

or

$$a_n=1+\frac{1}{n^2}(1+\epsilon(n))$$

which implies

$$|a_n-1|=\frac{1}{n^2}(1+\epsilon(n)).$$

$\exists N_1 \in \mathbb N $ such that

$$n\geq N_1 \implies -1<\epsilon(n)<1$$

and $N_2$ such that $n\geq N_2 \implies  \frac{2}{n^2}<\epsilon$ given by

$N_2=\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}\rfloor +1$.

at the end, we take $N=max(N_1,N_2)$

we check that

$$n\geq N \implies |a_n-1|<2\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can do basically no manipulation with the series at all. The proof must go as I've shown in the example in my original question.